# How to access cull mode and double sided programmatically within BodyEntity?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am setting my 3d model’s cull mode and double sided properties directly in my usdz file in my Scene graph. However, once it renders live real time, these properties are automatically reset to default. Is there a way I can access these properties programmatically through **BodyEntity** to ensure they're set when I render the character?

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new enum in RealityKit 2.0 for iOS 15 called [FaceCulling](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/materialparametertypes/faceculling):

```
enum MaterialParameterTypes.FaceCulling
```

with `front`, `back` and `none` cases. You can use it in PhysicallyBasedMaterial or in SimpleMaterial.

There's still no `doubleSided` property in RealityKit, like the popular property in SceneKit.

Comment: How would I access this from BodyEntity or ModelEntity in RealityKit?

Comment: Using ModelComponent — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408552/change-a-colour-of-an-object/67419742#67419742

Comment: @Mochi, also read this story, and leave your comment if you wish — https://medium.com/geekculture/the-top-9-most-in-demand-features-for-realitykit-3-0-c1a50f08909d

Comment: I have changed the culling to none and the back of the model is still not rendered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The working solution for Xcode 13.4.1., Swift 5.6.1.

```
if var material = particleME.model?.materials.first as? PhysicallyBasedMaterial {
    material.faceCulling = .none
    // Set transparency (if needed):
    // material.blending = .transparent(opacity: .init(floatLiteral:0.5))
    particleME.model?.materials = [material]
}
```

- Changing any property on the struct only changes the value since it's copied (by value). That's why I have to reassign it.
- Setting the `faceCulling` via the **Scene Graph Editor** via Settings -> Visibility -> "Cull _" is not possible because there is no "none" option.
- Your .usdz will most likely be a `Entity` (and not `ModelEntity`). Don't type cast it inside an `if` because it will most of the time fail.

NOTE: I have set the `transparency` via the **Scene Graph Editor** and using the above code reset it to 1.0. If you have edited your `.usdz` via the **SGE** it might be possible that modifying the materials array (like I did) will reset your previous settings. I had to set the blending to transparent to get my transparency back.

My suggestion is that when working with `RealityKit`, offload as many `.usdz` or 3D file changes to the 3D content creator because the API leaves a lot to be desired besides the stuff that does not work.

OTHER HELPFUL LINKS:

- [SGE two-sided material settings change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441696/how-to-specify-two-sided-material-for-realitykit-arview)