# Why is .generateBox method not working in RealityKit?

Tags: swiftui, realitykit, visionos

I am attempting to create a black box in RealityKit but the `.generateBox` method does not seem to work:

```
RealityView { content in
    let model = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 2, cornerRadius: 0),
    //                      mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.1),
                       materials: [UnlitMaterial()])
    content.add(model)
}
```

All other shapes are generated fine (cone, cylinder, sphere, plane) but when I try to create a box the canvas is empty:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of your box (in meters) exceeds the current window size. As you know, the [internal surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441696/how-to-specify-a-double-sided-material-in-realitykit/76163835#76163835) of models in RealityKit is not rendered by default. Thus you need to decrease the size of your box so that it fits within the window.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            let box = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.2))
            content.add(box)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]